# GWT replacement of JSPs with Java classes

Tags: java, jsp, gwt

I want execute some code in a browser that is different for another browser. I have written in `project.gwt.xml` file as follows

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DecoratedTabPanel"/>
    <any>
      <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie6"/>
    </any>
</replace-with>
```

and it is working fine.

But the problem is, I'm using some JSP pages. I want to call Java classes other then those JSPs for specific browsers. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Where is the connection between GWT and JSP?

Answer (score 0):

As Ingo states, showing a different JSP for different browsers has nothing to do with GWT. What you should be looking into is a conditional use of

```
<jsp:forward page="some url..." />
```

based on the browsers `user-agent`.

Cheers,